# Changing background image every time user scrolls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I scroll down a page, I want to change the background image from one image to another each time I scroll instead of scrolling down. How do I accomplish this?

Comment: By starting to code I guess. What have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a sample for you: https://jsfiddle.net/tp32z47w/

```
$(function(){

    var count = 0;
   var images = ['http://globe-views.com/dcim/dreams/sky/sky-01.jpg',       
                 'http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs70/i/2010/249/8/f/funny_sky_by_miffliness_stock-d2y71pa.jpg', 
                 'http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/010/cache/mackerel-sky_1054_990x742.jpg'
             ]

    $(window).scroll(function(){       

      $('body').css('background-image','url(' + images[count] + ')');
      $('body').css('background-repeat','no-repeat');

       count = count + 1;
       if(count == images.length) //reset the counter
          count = 0;
    });
});
```

You can have an array of image urls. Buy increasing the value of a counter variable in each scroll, you can move to the next item in the array by using the counter variable as the index of the array.

Comment: To count in JS you can use `count++;` instead.

Comment: This isn't gonna work. Scroll fires 20-60 times a second so the three images will be shown in about 50ms.